# Xamarin Android SDK and NDK dirs

Tags: xamarin, android-ndk, xamarin.android, android-sdk-tools

Can Xamarin point to a different location for Android SDK and the NDK than its normal directory in `<username>/Library/Developer/Xamarin/` where Xamarin installer has put them in, is there anything special to those locations for Xamarin, or the dir Android Studio Setup Wizard uses ok? For example to the `/usr/local/opt/android-sdk` where **homebrew** installs it.

The reason I want to be able to do this is to save disk space since I want to use another tool/ide, Deco for React Native development, as well as Xamarin that asks for Android SDK. Android SDK and Android NDK is more than 10GBs. Also this would keep me download and update time.

Is there anything specific for Xamarin with those directories it puts Android SDK and NDK in? If not, when I change those dirs from Xamarin preferences, will it take any other effort to set, configure Xamarin for that change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`Xamarin Studio` / `Preferences` / `Projects` / `Android`**

[image]

`Android Studio` Using the same directories:

[image]

Note: On my personal Mac, I have Android Studio pointing to where Xamarin installs the Android SDK/NDK.

Note: Xamarin does not make any changes to these directories, they are maintained by Google's installers and Xamarin content copies out of them when they to inflate a zip, etc...

You can change Xamarin to point to the SDK/NDK that Android Studio installs, your choice.

Comment: Is that means I can safely change to the dir Android Studio Setup Wizard sets up, but not to Xamarin downloads and sets fro Android SDK and NDK? I have worried maybe Xamarin makes some customizations for itself in that directories when it puts them under Xamarin a dir.

Comment: @Işık On my personal Mac, I have `Android Studio` pointing to where Xamarin installs the Android SDK/NDK. Xamarin does **not** make any changes to these directories, they are maintained by Google's installers and Xamarin copies out of them when they to inflate a zip, etc... You of course can change Xamarin to point to the SDK/NDK that `Android Studio` install, your choice

Comment: Ok. Can you add these to the answer though if this is correct the otherwise is correct, but just for directness of the accepted answer? With that does your Android Studio app build tasks function successfully?

Comment: @Işık Yes, Android Studio build steps work successfully.